# Cheese camera glitching

Tags: drivers, windows, lenovo, camera, cheese

On my Lenovo Ideapad 3 14ITL05, my cheese camera is glitching. Like it just works for a second and starts to replay one part like im moving my hand in the second and i stopped moving my hand and on the app, it is still moving. The drivers on the website are only for Windows 10 and 11 drivers. I dualbooted Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in this device, in Windows, the camera works perfectly. Any Ways to fix this problem? And also my Lenovo isn't Ubuntu-certified.

Comment: Google "Online webcam test". Does the camera glitch there as well?

Comment: Replying to "Archisman Panigrahi"- No it does not, i tried to video in the cheese app but i could not see anything, i can only see white lines. But the Google webcam test works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is reinstall cheese and then see if it is still glitching from there. The way that you can do that is by typing in the terminal `sudo apt-get --reinstall install cheese` this should reinstall cheese for you. If cheese is still not working, I would suggest trying some other webcam apps and see if they work. Some examples are Webcamoid, Camorama, and Kamoso.